# Priority web SDK method getSubform returns parent form

Tags: priority-web-sdk

Parent form is the same I only change the company in the request and on some company i get parent form instead of sub form. So for example I have default company make a request get some form. According to user actions I change company in form request( but it is the same form name).

After that I try to get some sub form and on one particular company/form get the parent sub form instead of a child.

I already read topic about the problem that looks the same, but  get rows and set active rows doesn't help me.
Do somebody had this problem?

```js
async getDocuments(formName: string, getMappedRows: Function) {
        const _currentOrderType = this.priorityService.getCurrentOrderType();
        const _groupForm        = await this.priorityService.getFormBridge(eSharedForm.GROUP.toString());
        await _groupForm.setActiveRow(_currentOrderType.company.key);
        const ListForm = await this.priorityService.getSubFormBridge(formName.toString(), _groupForm);
//some more logic 
}

private async _getSubForm(name: string, form: any) {
            try {
                const subform = await form.startSubForm(name, this.onMessage, this.onUpdate);
                debugger;
                return subform;
            } catch (e) {
                this.subForms[name] = undefined;
                const _e = JSON.stringify(e);
                console.log(`[PriorityService::_getSubForm] Error starting subform '${name}': ${_e}`);
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

and after that i see the same form as before

Comment: Can you share you code?

Comment: @rozalex its pretty  generic but ok `private async _getSubForm(name: string, form: any) {
        try {
            const subform = await form.startSubForm(name, this.onMessage, this.onUpdate);
            debugger;
            return subform;
        } catch (e) {
            this.subForms[name] = undefined;
            const _e = JSON.stringify(e);
            console.log(`[PriorityService::_getSubForm] Error starting subform '${name}': ${_e}`);
            throw e;
        }
    }`

Comment: This doesn't show where you setActiveRow or get a row. You need to activate or "select" a row on the parent with one of these methods before you call the sub form. If you already do it, please edit your question and share the code. Also.. please try to format it so it will be readable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your code snippet what `getSubFormBridge` does or what is the value of `_currentOrderType.company.key` Is it numeric? is this the number of the row you want to retrieve?

When you start the Parent form, try to set `autoRetrieveFirstRows` to 1, which means, select the first row of the current form. If you know for sure what row you want to retrieve, pass the correct row number.

For example:
`const form = await priority.formStart('ORDERS', this.onError, this.onSuccess, '', 1);`

If you need to filter first and than select a row, use `setActiveRow` method and pass it the number of the row you want to retrieve. (Starts from 1)

Once the row is selected, retrieve the subform. For example:

```
const subform = await form.startSubForm("ORDERITEMS");
```